# Addition formula for generalized Laguerre polynomials

Tags: special-functions, generating-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, hermite-polynomials, laguerre-polynomials

For the Hermite polynomials, there is the following addition formula

[image]

Is there a similar formula for the generalized Laguerre Polynomials, in particular for $a=b=1/2$.

I.e. what is
$L^m_k(0.5x + 0.5 y)$ in terms of $L^m_k(x), L^m_k(y)$?

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Recurrence_relations), the addition formula for the generalized Laguerre polynomials is

$$L_{n}^{\alpha +\beta +1}(x+y)=\sum _{i=0}^{n}L_{i}^{\alpha}(x)L_{n-i}^{\beta}(y)$$

So, letting $\alpha=m-1$ and $\beta=0$, we have
$$L_{k}^{m}(0.5x+0.5y)=\sum _{i=0}^{k}L_{i}^{m-1}(0.5x)L_{k-i}(0.5y)\tag1$$

---

**Added** :

> I need the Laguerres to be evaluated at x and y, not 0.5x and so on

The following may help.

Using [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Multiplication_theorems) of the multiplication theorems

$$e^{(1-t)z}L_{n}^{\alpha}(zt)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(1-t)^{k}z^{k}}{k!}}L_{n}^{\alpha +k}(z)$$

we can write

$$\begin{align}L_{i}^{m-1}(0.5x)&=e^{-x/2}\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x/2)^s}{s!}L_{i}^{m-1+s}(x)
\\\\L_{k-i}(0.5y)&=e^{-y/2}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{(y/2)^t}{t!}L_{k-i}^{t}(y)\end{align}$$
So, it follows from $(1)$ that
$$L_{k}^{m}(0.5x+0.5y)=e^{-(x+y)/2}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\bigg(\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x/2)^s}{s!}L_{i}^{m-1+s}(x)\bigg)\bigg(\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{(y/2)^t}{t!}L_{k-i}^{t}(y)\bigg)$$

Comment: Unfortunately I need the Laguerres to be evaluated at x and y, not 0.5x and so on. I updated by question

Comment: @user2224350 : I added some explanations.

Comment: But this expression now involves an infinite series. Is it possible to get a formula with only a finite amount of terms?